# How do you change the Forecolor?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am having trouble changing the forecolor of `DataGridView cells`. I have multiple *runtime* generated `DataGridView` and I am using the following code:

```
For Each tbp As TabPage In frmTimingP2P.tabctrlTimingTable.TabPages
   For Each ctrl As Control In tbp.Controls
        Dim dgv As DataGridView = TryCast(ctrl, DataGridView)
        If Not dgv Is Nothing Then
            For Each dc As DataGridViewColumn In dgv.Columns
                If dc.Name.EndsWith("Gain/Loss") Then
                    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
                        If Not dr.Cells(dc.Index).Value Is DBNull.Value Then
                            If dr.Cells(dc.Index).Value = 0 Then
                                dr.Cells(dc.Index).Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue
                            ElseIf dr.Cells(dc.Index).Value < 0 Then
                                dr.Cells(dc.Index).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
                            ElseIf dr.Cells(dc.Index).Value > 0 Then
                                dr.Cells(dc.Index).Style.ForeColor = Color.Green
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
            dgv.Refresh()
        End If
    Next
Next
```

This code works fine ONLY on the currently focused DataGridView, but not in others `DataGridview`.

I have revised my code and have now come up with the following:

```
Private Sub dgvOverview_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvOverview.CellFormatting
    Dim dgv As New DataGridView
    dgv = sender

    If dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name.EndsWith("Gain/Loss") Then
        If e.Value IsNot DBNull.Value Then
            Dim intCellValue As Integer = CType(e.Value, Integer)
            If intCellValue = 0 Then
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue
            ElseIf intCellValue > 0 Then
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green
            ElseIf intCellValue < 0 Then
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

This all works well. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much better approach would be to handle DataGridView CellFormatting event. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx for more information.

Comment: This did work for me, but I have another issue. I have revised the code above.